# How do I set an environment variable in the shebang (#!) of a script that will be run by Bash?

Tags: bash, unix

Or, why doesn't this work, assuming you correctly set the file as executable? (On my system it just hangs, but can be killed with ^C.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env TEST=TEST python
print('hello')
```

While this does:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print('hello')
```

As does this:

```
[fred@pc build]$ /usr/bin/env TEST=TEST python hello.py 
hello
```

Comment: Works for me (Mac), even using `print(os.environ['TEST'])` to check.

Comment: If you have `strace` on your system, run your script using something like  `strace -f script-name` (the `-f` means "follow child processes").  My guess is that it is `python` waiting on `stdin`, i.e. the keyboard, when it appear to be "hanging", so you should see a line starting `read(0,...` from the `strace` output.  Failing that, hit <CTRL>+D for EOF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since version 8.30 env has the option -S, which make things
work also in linux:

Use

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S TEST=TEST python
```

Answer (score 6):

On some systems, including Linux, the effect of the

```
#!/usr/bin/env TEST=TEST python
```

line in 'hello.py' if you run it with './hello.py' is the same as running

```
/usr/bin/env 'TEST=TEST python' ./hello.py
```

Notice that 'TEST=TEST python' is all one argument.  This causes 'env' to set the `TEST` environment variable to `'TEST python'` and then run `./hello.py` with [exec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)).  Then the shebang line is processed again, and the process repeats recursively.  The overall effect is to have `env` execed over and over again until the process is interrupted.  If you run `top` on the system while the execing is going on you'll see a very busy process.

See the [Shebang (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) Wikipedia article for information about how the `#!` mechanism works.  It includes some details of differences between how it is handled on different systems.

It's not possible to set environment variables on the shebang line on Linux, and many other systems.  You'll need to either set them in the program itself or, if that is not appropriate, use a wrapper program (e.g. a trivial shell program) to run the Python program.